# Strip publishing master-page for anonymous users

Tags: master-page, performance, css, javascript

Is it ok to strip a masterpage for all SharePoint scripts and styles?
We have custom CSS and all of our scripts are JQuery.
Even CQWP will have custom rendering.

The reason we want to do this is so end users will get a lighter version of the page.
Since it's a publishing page all end users will be anonymous.
We will include all scripts, styles and ribbon for logged in users, so the custom layout have to work for logged in users as well.

Answer (score 1):

(Note) It seems this is somewhat answered here:

[Has anyone optimized the front-end (css/javascript files) of a SharePoint site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/127/has-anyone-optimized-the-front-end-css-javascript-files-of-a-sharepoint-site)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for most styles, but keep in mind you'll need a good bit of stuff for the ribbon and other SharePoint UI controls. Can you completely replace the SP2010 UI? Sure... but you're likely looking at a considerable effort.

Comment: I'm keeping styles and scripts for ribbon when the user is logged in. The ribbon will not be visible for anonymous users, so the scripts and styles I miss will only be for existing Web Parts and such, which we probably can style ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to hide ribbon fully from anonymous users and then only leave the CSS that's truly needed, like corev4.css

Comment: We even strip away corev4.css, and we had no problems so far.

Comment: Nice, have to try that then :)